# How can threads communicate with each other in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing two Python programs: one that runs an algorithm on a graph, and one that draws the graph using matplotlib. How do I send a point to be graphed from the algorithm to the graphing program using Python?

Comment: I'd start looking here: http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) module:

> The `Queue` module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It
>   is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be
>   exchanged safely between multiple threads. The `Queue` class in this
>   module implements all the required locking semantics.

I see that your question is tagged `multithreading`, but your question seems to be defining it as multiple processes.  If you have multiple processes, use `Queue` from the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) which "is a near clone of `Queue.Queue`".

If you need two way communication, use `muliprocessing.Pipe`.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something very similar when I had matplotlib in a wxPython window.  I used pubsub and wx.CallAfter for this purpose.  See [this link](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/) for an example.